# JWPlayer dialog box not showing on full screen

Tags: jwplayer

JWPlayer Noob here...

I have a jwplayer and a dialog box showing up at 10 second intervals. It works fine unless the player is on full screen. Then it doens't show at all.

Here's the dialog code:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 130,
    resizable: false,
    appendTo: "#apitester",
    position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: "#apitester" },

    buttons: {
        Confirm: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            //MAKE CALL TO CF BACKEND

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes full screen is full screen.  Nothing is going to show on top of it, as the player is essentially a giant flash movie, and has taken over complete control at that point.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized the dialog function is of JQueryUI, and not JWPlayer. Is there a dialog function for JWPlayer?

Comment: You have to understand that jwplayer is a flash movie.  The stuff around it is just marshaling parameters to it.  Like all browser plugins, when a plugin runs, the browser has given over control to it.  When in full screen, flash has taken over the display.  The only way you are getting something over that is to have the flash movie allow for it.  In this case, you have to look at what the jwplayer allows.  It does allow for overlays like http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/open-video-ads/22835/using-ad-notices/  In short, you want to look at options for the jwplayer.

Comment: Indeed, this is because in Flash when a video player is in full screen mode, it takes over the entire page, no html/js divs will show up on top of it.